# Why fgets skips input after convert char to int in looping?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm curious why fgets skips input after convert char to int in looping? How can I solved it?

Here's the code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct TanggalLahir {
  int Tanggal;
  int Bulan;
  int Tahun;
};

struct Dosen {
  char NoDosen[255];
  char Nama[255];
  struct TanggalLahir tgllahir;
};

int main() {

  struct Dosen dosen[5];
  
  char NoDosen[255];
  char Nama[255];

  int Tanggal;
  char Tanggal_str[4];
  
  int Bulan;
  char Bulan_str[4];
  
  int Tahun;
  char Tahun_str[8];

  printf("Pengisian data dosen \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("Nomor Dosen: ");
    fgets(NoDosen, sizeof(NoDosen), stdin);
    NoDosen[strcspn(NoDosen, "\n")] = '\0';
    strcpy(dosen[i].NoDosen, NoDosen);

    printf("Nama: ");
    fgets(Nama, sizeof(Nama), stdin);
    Nama[strcspn(Nama, "\n")] = '\0';
    strcpy(dosen[i].Nama, Nama);

    printf("Tanggal: ");
    fgets(Tanggal_str, sizeof(Tanggal_str), stdin);
    Tanggal = strtol(Tanggal_str, NULL, 10);
    dosen[i].tgllahir.Tanggal = Tanggal;

    printf("Bulan: ");
    fgets(Bulan_str, sizeof(Bulan_str), stdin);
    Bulan = strtol(Bulan_str, NULL, 10);
    dosen[i].tgllahir.Tanggal = Tanggal;

    printf("Tahun: ");
    fgets(Tahun_str, sizeof(Tahun_str), stdin);
    Tahun = strtol(Tahun_str, NULL, 10);
    dosen[i].tgllahir.Tahun = Tahun;
  }

  printf("Pengisian data dosen selesai. \n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("Nomor Dosen: %s \n", dosen[i].NoDosen);
    printf("Nama: %s \n", dosen[i].Nama);
    printf("Tanggal Lahir \n");
    printf("Tanggal: %d \n", dosen[i].tgllahir.Tanggal);
    printf("Bulan: %d \n", dosen[i].tgllahir.Bulan);
    printf("Tahun: %d \n", dosen[i].tgllahir.Tahun);
  }
}
```

Is that because I do conversion char to int with `strtol()` function? If so, how can I solved it?

Here's the example output program in my terminal.

```
~/Learning/learn-c 
❯ ./data_dosen
Pengisian data dosen 
Nomor Dosen: D1234
Nama: Kresna
Tanggal: 6
Bulan: Tahun: 1995
Nomor Dosen: Nama: Nuna
Tanggal: 8
Bulan: Tahun: 1996
Pengisian data dosen selesai. 
Nomor Dosen: D1234 
Nama: Kresna 
Tanggal Lahir 
Tanggal: 6 
Bulan: 0 
Tahun: 199 
Nomor Dosen: 5 
Nama: Nuna 
Tanggal Lahir 
Tanggal: 8 
Bulan: 0 
Tahun: 199
```

As you can see that field "Bulan" and "Nomor Dosen" skipped by program. What I expect that input field "Bulan" and "Nomor Dosen" don't skip by fgets so the expected output program like below:

```
~/Learning/learn-c 
❯ ./data_dosen
Pengisian data dosen 
Nomor Dosen: D1234
Nama: Kresna
Tanggal: 6
Bulan: 5
Tahun: 1995
Nomor Dosen: D33345
Nama: Nuna
Tanggal: 8
Bulan: 7
Tahun: 1996
Pengisian data dosen selesai. 
Nomor Dosen: D1234 
Nama: Kresna 
Tanggal Lahir 
Tanggal: 6 
Bulan: 5 
Tahun: 1995
Nomor Dosen: 5 
Nama: Nuna 
Tanggal Lahir 
Tanggal: 8 
Bulan: 7 
Tahun: 1996
```

I'm curious is that because of my data type "Bulan" is not enough or maybe else?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a minimal version of the file you pipe into your program along with expected and actual output.

Comment: "show a minimal version of the file" Text, not a picture of the text.

Comment: Already add minimal version of output program in text. Thanks for your advice Jeff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your strings longer.

`char Bulan_str[4]` isn't large enough for you to enter a 4-digit number. It needs to be large enough for the number, the newline, and the null terminator.

When you call `fgets(Bulan_str, sizeof(Bulan_str), stdin)` and type a 4-digit number, it will read the first 3 characters of the number into the string. The rest of the input line are left in the input buffer.

Then the next time you call `fgets()`, it will read the rest of that line from the buffer, so it doesn't wait for you to type anything.

So declare all your input strings to be at least 2 bytes larger than the largest possible value someone could enter.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your advice. So, after I increase length of `Bulan_str` and `Tahun_str` to `255` like `Bulan_str[255]` and `Tahun_str[255]`. The program run as I expect.